# Limit(s) on the obligation to forgive?

Tags: halacha, sin, forgiving-mechilah

There's a common adage, based on the Rambam, that if a person harms someone else, and then seeks forgiveness three times, the aggrieved party is obligated to forgive the person, or else carry the sin. What limits, if any, are there on one's obligation to forgive someone else?

- If a person harmed someone and clearly regrets it, but they are too embarrassed to ask outright for forgiveness
- If a person asks for forgiveness but clearly isn't regretful
- If the harm was so severe it altered the life of the aggrieved party in some way
- If the harm never came to fruition, but the potential harm would have been severe, and/or the intention was to severely harm the aggrieved party
- If the harm was caused by a non-Jew or a non-religious Jew

Does the aggrieved party have an obligation to forgive, and/or carry the sin if he or she refuses to forgive the person who caused the harm?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17412/are-there-unforgiveable-sins and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10360/do-i-have-to-forgive-a-repeat-offender (In my head b/c Monica recently [suggested them](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10911751#10911751) for tweets.)